# on the opposite side of the desk from his own

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here's the sentence:

> Then he arranged the chairs on the opposite side of the desk from his
>   own.

What does "from his own" mean in the context?
Thank you in advance

Comment: From his own chair.

Comment: Does it mean that he arranged the chairs with his own one, together all the chairs?

Comment: *Then he arranged the chairs on the opposite side of the desk from his own [chair].* Picture a teacher sitting at a desk with, say, a classroom of chairs facing him.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot!

Comment: I would tend to read it as "on the opposite side from his own side". The fact that his chair would be on his side of the desk is incidental to it's being his side. It's a bit like "The King's side of the table was served first" or "The sun was shining on my side of the street"